# How to fetch metadata (image, title, description) from any url in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch, metadata

I want to fetch metadata (title, image, description) from a url like a Medium article and then display it as a post on my blog. How to do it. I am using ReactJS

I tried using fetch and axios.get but it always shows error in the browser's console. 
"NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://medium.com/s/jessica-valenti/hateful-fox-news-rhetoric-can-do-real-world-harm-52e26008caa5. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [open-graph-scraper](https://github.com/jshemas/openGraphScraper) and make the request from backend-server. It works like a delight

Comment: I was also having this issue, Thanks for solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to request request URL's that don't have the CORS header (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`).
This is due security reasons of medium and other pages. They need to actively enable that header to allow clients to request it from JS.

You will need a backend that does the request for you (nodejs, python, php etc). You could also try to use `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`.

Comment: Doesn't OpenGraph solve this?

Comment: this link not working